# Prevent deleting files in XCFE

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, xfce, trash

I use XFCE 4.12 on Ubuntu 18.04 ; and I would like to avoid deleting files inadvertently from the right-click menu:

[image: right-click menu XFCE]

Both "Move to Trash" and "Delete" menu items permanently delete my files ; which can be really dangerous when I release my mouse button at the wrong item (I deleted a folder instead of renaming it).

- **Is there a way to remove those menu items?**
- **Or can I disable file deletion from XFCE and only allow it from the command line?**

(I must have a problem with the configuration of the trash on my system since "Move to Trash should send the files to the trash but that does not happen: files are deleted instead. However, this would not be a problem if I didn't have the menu item.)

I also [posted on the official XFCE forum](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=66181#p66181).

**EDIT:**

I don't have "Show action to permanently delete files and folders" under "Behaviour" in the Edit/Preferences menu in my XFCE version (4.12). It seems XFCE 4.12 is the official version for Ubuntu 18.04 ; so I am not sure I should force the update to the latest version...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To stop showing the "Delete" command, deselect "Show action to permanently delete files and folders" under "Behaviour" in the Edit/Preferences menu.

The "Move to Trash" should not delete permanently, rather move it to your Wastebasket.

To see what's in your Wastebasket do:

```
gio list Trash://
```

Your Trash folder should be in `$HOME/.local/share/Trash` - does that folder exist?

It's a good idea to add the "Wastebasket Applet" to your panel.

Comment: Great! I realized that the trash is working! The only strange behavior is that it always remains empty on the navigation window (it does not refresh) but I can use trash-restore to restore my files ; so I am happy :)

Comment: Now my only wish is to remove "delete" from the right-click menu in XFCE 4.12 (or make sure I can update XFCE safely in Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Hm.. strange - with me, the wastebasket icon updates immediately. Maybe have a chat with the folks over at https://forum.xfce.org/ - there's good help to be had. Didn't the "delete" go away when you deselect "Show action to permanently delete files and folders" in the Thunar settings? Again, it does with me - and I would expect it to work in your Thunar too :-)